# Is there a way in postman to assert multiple comma separated values in single column of csv file?

Tags: csv, dynamic, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am new to post man and I want to parse a csv file having comma separated values in single column for implementing assertion. Is there a way to implement this?

**Note:** The values I want to assert needs to be fetched from CSV file and will be dynamic for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

ya it will be passed as a string , if you want to convert it to array use :

```
console.log(data["columnname"].split(","))
```

eg csv:

```
a,b,c,d
"1,2,3,4,5,5,6",2,2,e
```

so the column value a will have the value "1,2,3,4,5,5,6" for the first iteration